# How to find second latest ( accessed) file in Windows folder using powershell

Tags: powershell, text-files, known-folders

I have a folder containing 5 files.

I want to skip the first latest file and want the name of second latest file. How I can do this using PowerShell commands?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1 -ExpandProperty name
```

This uses `Get-ChildItem` to return just files.

It then uses the `Sort-Object` cmdlet to sort them by their `LastAccessTime` value in Descending order (so the most recently accessed is at the top).

It then uses `Select-Object` to skip the 1st item in the collection (the most recently accessed) and return just the first result of the remaining items (i.e the second most recently accessed).

Finally the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object` is used to return just the `Name` property as its string type.

Comment: I just realised you said "accessed", in which case this should have been sorted on LastAccessTime. I will update my answer.